# Non convenient date format. Time zone must be defined as "UTC" error message

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in programming with R, I have a csv file with 4 columns :

```
DateR        P   E    Q
2017-09-01 0.20 4.6 0.263
2017-09-02 0.15 3.0 0.157
...
2021-09-01 0.57 8.6 0.574
```

I want to run a code with a airGRteaching packaging and I have this error message that shows up :
Non convenient date format. Time zone must be defined as "UTC"

I had already convert the class of the dataR to POSIXct.

Please any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the class to POSIXct as follows:

`df$DateR = as.POSIXct(df$DateR, 'UTC')`

Substitute `df` with the name of your dataframe.

Comment: If this doesn't work, show us your data format; show the output of `str(df)` (again substituting `df` with your own dataframe)